# ¿A qué nivel se debe comprender física cuántica para programar en Q#?

Tags: computación-cuántica

Buenos días. 
Para poder programar en Q#, ¿se necesita entender profundamente física cuántica, o con unos conceptos generales basta?

Pequeño complemento:
La verdad, esto de las computadoras cuánticas me atrae mucho. Entiendo los conceptos generales, ya que estoy en primer año de Ingeniería en Sistemas y me falta mucho para lograr entender a fondo cuántica. Quiero programar en Q# pero lo vi complejo. No me asusta que sea difícil de aprender, pero sí que no pueda entenderlo gracias a que me faltan conocimientos. Por eso la pregunta, para saber si meterme en este campo o esperar a tener física avanzada.
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Según Ignacio Cirac el desarrollo de software cuantico no implicara para los desarolladores grandes conocimientos de fisica cuantica, simplemente se necesitaran comprender pequeños conceptos (se nos darán herramientas para emplear sin tener que conocer su trasfondo).

Te dejo una  [conferencia en youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJ3r6btgzBM)
de este señor bastante actual, donde explica en lo que está trabajando y como puede afectar todo este tema.